# JS изменение css

Tags: javascript, ajax

Есть вот такой запрос

```
 $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/mgr/photo/crop',
            data: {src: src, data: data, id: id},
            success: function (result) {
                $('#cropImg').cropper('destroy');
                
                UIkit.modal('#modal-photo').hide();
                $('div[data-id="'+id+'"]').find('img').attr('src', result);

                    $('a[data-id="'+id+'"]').css('background-image', result);

            }
          });
```

После выполнения обновляется img внутри div. Как мне сделать так, чтобы еще обновлялся background у тега A?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-image

```
$('a[data-id="'+id+'"]').css('background-image', "url('" + result + "')");
```